# Swift : Switch nil value in case with Integer

Tags: swift, null, switch-statement, case

my problem in code :

```
  if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "carT") as? String {
            carTpass.text = x
        }

        if let x2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "carM") as? String {
            carMpass.text = x2
        }
        if let x3 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "carCom") as? String {
            carCompass.text = x3
        }

 @IBAction func calc(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let statusCode:Int = Int(carMpass.text!)!

        switch (carTpass.text ,carCompass.text, statusCode) {
        case ("BMW"?,"X"?,2008 ... 2010):
            result.text = "Yes"
        default:
            result.text = "No"
        }
```

now my problem is :

if the statusCode is nil, the app will crash because the unwrapped Integer , how can I solve that ?

carTpass.text , carCompass.text , and carMpass.text they are data from another View Controller (tableView)

Comment: Optionals are one of the most essential concepts in Swift. Please read the language guide and learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `if let` as you use in other places

```
@IBAction func calc(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = carMpass.text, let statusCode = Int(text) {
        switch (carTpass.text ,carCompass.text, statusCode) {
        case ("BMW"?,"X"?,2008 ... 2010):
            result.text = "Yes"
        default:
            result.text = "No"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply optional unwrapping for ranges as well

```
let statusCode = carMpass.text.flatMap(Int.init)
switch (carTpass.text ,carCompass.text, statusCode) {
case ("BMW"?, "X"?, (2008 ... 2010)?):
    result.text = "Yes"
default:
    result.text = "No"
}
```